# Dynamically reference an IBOutlet in Swift?

Tags: swift, iboutlet

I have a view controller with 100 IBOutlets that I want to hide or display depending on whether the name of that IBOutlet is found as a key in Dictionary.

How on earth do I do this?  My intuition points me to

```
for item in Dict {
    // try to refer to an IBOutlet using data from my Dictionary 
    self.\(item.key).hidden = false
}
```

Swift obviously throws up and error when I try to do this.

I'm new to this and not even sure what to call what I'm trying to do.  Is it even possible to do this?  Is there a much better way to do this?

I'd like to avoid writing 100 "if" statements.

Comment: I am pretty sure that having 100, or even 40 outlets says that there is something very bad with your architecture. Accessing variables by their name is another antipattern. Please share more of your code and we can *then* help you to fix the *real problem*.

Comment: I have 100 square UIViews that appear in the View Controller in specific locations.  I want to show or hide them dynamically based on data.  I know that I could draw them programatically, but I believe that means also writing 400 constraints programmatically (height, width, X position, Y position), and that sounds very painful and complicated.

Comment: It will be definitely easier than to create several hundreds of constraints in IB. Also note that you don't have to use autolayout. This is one of the cases when using simple old autoresizing would be much simpler. Even creating constraints for all the views is a work for about 30 lines tops. Also, when using IB, you can still connect all the outlets into one array and then sort them by position. You will have 1 outlet instead of 100 outlets and you can use simple indexing.

Comment: For my own understanding what does "use autolayout" mean?  Does that mean "use Interface builder"?  Or does it refer to something else?

Comment: autolayout = explicit constraints, autoresizing = use frames without constraints, with autoresizing mask (the frames are internally translated to constraints), nowadays used only in code.

Comment: It doesn't looks like a good design, But if you want, you can find each view with tag values.   self.view.viewWithTag(key as! Int) so set a tag to each view

Comment: @RJE tags are yet another antipattern.

Comment: @Sulthan On the programmatic side I don't understand how that's doable either.  I can create a loop from 1 to 100 that will add a subview to a given view each time.  Yes.  But I need to name each of those views after "i" within the loop so I can position them each uniquely.  I'm back to the same problem of needing to declare variables or reference variables programmatically.

Comment: OK.  I guess I can apply my constraints and settings to each view within my 1-100 loop before adding it as a subview.  Blah. Constraints are a pain to work with programmatically. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2):

There should be lots of other, better ways to do this.

1. Have you considered adding all the outlets to dictionary?

   ```
   var outletDict: [String: UIView] = ["outlet1": outlet1, "outlet2": outlet2,
       "outlet3", outlet3 ... "outlet100": outlet100]
   ```

Then you can just access the outlets using *this* dictionary:

```
for item in Dict {
    outletDict[item.key].hidden = false
}
```

2. Have you tried not using outlets and dynamically create the views instead? I mean, it's really rare to have 100 outlets. I wonder how you connected them all. They should be in a pattern or something. If that's true, you can create your views with for loops and add them to the dictionary mentioned above.
3. If none of the above applies to you, the only solution I can think of is this:

   ```
   for item in Dict {
       let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
       let outlet = mirror.children.filter { $0.label == item.key }.first?.value as? UIView
       outlet?.hidden = false
   }
   ```

Comment: The outlets are square UIViews in a slightly intricate pattern.  Adding them as subviews programmatically feels like a thing I could figure out.  Generating 400 constraints programmatically feels very intimidating.

Comment: If they are square views in a grid like formation, have you considered using `UICollectionView`? @bflora2

Comment: It's not an exact grid.  It's got a weird, uneven shape.

Comment: @bflora2 i just realized that you can use tags: set each view's `tag` to a unique value in IB, then you can use `viewWithTag` to get the views. Your `Dict` can just be `[Int: UIView]` instead of `[String: UIView]`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sulthan that this is a case were constraints and IB are poor design. I coded this up as a template the should help you out. Notes:

- The global width and height variables are there to make it easy to change. Poor coding practice but there for testing purposes.
- I split out the creation of the subviews from the backgroundColor choice to give you an idea on how to iterate through the subviews quickly.
- The "seedValue" piece is probably not needed for you. I needed it to differentiate between rows.
- Most importantly, since you only state you have 100 "UIViews", I would recommend subclassing UIView as something. Not only can you create a convenience initializer (making is easy to init additional properties and common subviews), you can iterate through the superview's subviews as your subclass type, allowing you to use the tag property elsewhere.

The code:

```
let width:CGFloat = 20
let height:CGFloat = 20

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    create100subviews()
    for view in view.subviews as [UIView] {
        color(view)
    }
}

func create100subviews() {
    for i in 1...100 {
        let newView = UIView(frame: calculateFrame(width: width, height: height, tag: i))
        newView.tag = i
        view.addSubview(newView)
    }
}

func calculateFrame(width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat, tag:Int) -> CGRect {
    let (row,column) = calculateRowAndColumn(tag: tag)
    return CGRect(x: ((CGFloat(column)*width)+20), y: ((CGFloat(row)*height)+40), width: width, height: height)
}

func calculateRowAndColumn(tag:Int) -> (Int,Int) {
    // the returned tuple (row,column) is zero-based
    var row:Int = 0
    var column = tag
    while column > 10 {
        row += 1
        column -= 10
    }
    column -= 1
    return (row,column)
}

func color(_ view: UIView) {
    let (row,column) = calculateRowAndColumn(tag: view.tag)
    var seedValue = column + row + 1
    while seedValue > 10 {
        seedValue -= 10
    }
    switch seedValue {
    case 1:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    case 2:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    case 3:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    case 4:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    case 5:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    case 6:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    case 7:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    case 8:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    case 9:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    case 10:
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up drawing them programmatically.  It took about 4 hours to figure out how to implement the constraints but it works now.